# Is storage a Iaas or Paas

Tags: azure

While considering Azure storage options like Table, Queue, Blob we have been only allowed to write applications around but not allowed to have full control like in case of VMs where we can decide OS, maintain, secure etc. Considering these limitation, is Azure storage a PaaS or IaaS? please suggest & justify.

Most of the articles lists storage as IaaS & thats the confusion, did they mean different thing other than Azure storage? If so please provide examples of PaaS storage and IaaS storage

Comment: I know this is old, but according to MS, Storage is Iaas: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-iaas/

Comment: I agree it is IaaS

Answer (score 2):

In my mind Azure Storage is a PaaS solution (since you do not have to manage os updates, load balancing, performance allocation etc). You are provided with a rest api, and you act against that rest api. IaaS storage would be a storage inside virtual machine(s). Since you have to manage the VMs in order for that storage to work

But i'd consider this somewhat opinion based, hence I'm not saying this is 100% true.

Comment: According to MS [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-iaas/) it is under IaaS

Comment: re-read the answer. storage provided by azure is paas by definition - you dont manage the OS, you dont manage the patches, you dont manage provisioning etc